# Array inside an object

Tags: javascript

```
var Obj = {

    StateValues: ['AL','AK','AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
    'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND',
    'OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY'],

    getItemRow: function(itemValue) {
     var myPosition=-1
       for (i=0;i<this.StateValues.length;i++) {
          if(this.StateValues[i]==itemValue) {
            myPosition = i;
             break;
         }
      }
      return myPosition;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this piece of code. Am i declaring the correct way. The issue started after adding the array in my Object.

Comment: are you getting an error? if so, what?

Comment: You haven't provided anything that demonstrates an actual issue. Any chance you copy/pasted the StateValues? Are you getting an Invalid Token error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `this` wrongly. It is referring to `window` (the global object).Try this instead:

```
var Obj = {

    StateValues: ['AL','AK','AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
    'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND',
    'OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY'],

    getItemRow: function(itemValue) {
     var myPosition=-1
       for (i=0;i<Obj.StateValues.length;i++) {
          if(Obj.StateValues[i]==itemValue) {
            myPosition = i;
             break;
         }
      }
      return myPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run `alert(Obj.getItemRow('AZ'))` and it works just fine using `this` keyword.

Comment: @Genzer: You're correct - I was recently facing this problem and found that `this` wasn't working. I don't know the answer (nor the problem actually) since his code *does* just work.

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing semicolon at the very end.

After making this change, the declaration **syntax** checks out on jslint.com (at least when I disable checking for messy whitespace and the like).

However, don't forget to declare `i` with the `var` keyword and write `Obj` rather than `this`.

Without knowing anything about the alleged "issue", we cannot comment further.